# Issue with IE 11

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I'm using custom css in wordpress to change my themes copyright at the bottom. It works fine in chrome and other browsers but in IE 11 it just shows blank.

Any way to fix? thanks

Site: http://www.corebusinesssa.co.za/Test/

CSS:

```
.footer-socket-wrapper .copyright {
visibility: hidden;
}

.footer-socket-wrapper .copyright:before {
visibility: visible;
content: 'Copyright © 2016 Avmark Systems - Created by Core Business SA';
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Try the double colon syntax for **before** (that is, ::before)

Comment: Try using a span `span:before{visibility: visible;
content: 'Copyright © 2016 Avmark Systems - Created by Core Business SA';
font-weight:bold;}`?

Comment: Semantically, this belongs in the actual markup, not in CSS.

Comment: Just tested in IE11, changing to a span fixes the issue

Comment: You mean like this? 

.footer-socket-wrapper .copyright span:before {
 visibility: visible;
     content: 'Copyright © 2016 Avmark Systems - Created by Core     Business SA';
    font-weight:bold;
    }

doesn't seem to work unless i did it wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue (I don't know what) with using `:before` and `:after` in IE.  Technically they are pseudo code so IE must clamp down on standards more than other browsers.

In IE11 I got it working by changing the html class to `span` from `copyright`:

```
<div class="span">Copyright © 2016 <a title="Avmark Systems" href="http://www.corebusinesssa.co.za/Test/"><span>Avmark Systems</span></a>. Powered by <a title="WordPress" href="http://wordpress.org" target="_blank"><span>WordPress</span></a>. Theme: Spacious by <a title="ThemeGrill" href="http://themegrill.com/themes/spacious" target="_blank" rel="designer"><span>ThemeGrill</span></a>.</div>
```

The change will also need to be applied to the CSS:

```
.footer-socket-wrapper .span:before {
visibility: visible;
content: 'Copyright © 2016 Avmark Systems - Created by Core Business SA';
font-weight:bold;
}
```

It's not very clean but it works.

You could also try changing

```
.footer-socket-wrapper .copyright {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.footer-socket-wrapper .copyright {

}
```

Comment out or remove the visibility line and see if that works.

Comment: Thing is im using a free wordpress theme so i cant edit the html, if i could i wouldn't need to do the css :P

Comment: editing the copyright is in pro only, heres the theme im using http://themegrill.com/themes/spacious/ im using free one

Comment: doing that adds it twice for some reason and the original copyright shows up, that class hides the powered by wordpress

Comment: Theres nothing more I can do unless you buy the theme and apply the first fix

Comment: You could still mark as answered.  The problem is solved you just cant apply the fixes